# zpool import can't import an online pool

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I rebooted my Ubuntu 15.04 server and found that my ZFS pool did not import. I'm puzzled as to why this is happening. Here is the output.

```
root@ubuntuserver:/# zpool import
pool: store1
id: 15396841088549477814
state: ONLINE
action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier.
config:

    store1      ONLINE
      sdb       ONLINE
      sdc       ONLINE
      sda       ONLINE
      sde       ONLINE
```

Looks great! So I try to import...

```
root@ubuntuserver:/# zpool import store1
cannot import 'store1': one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

Not sure why. Try it forcibly.

```
root@ubuntuserver:/# zpool import -f store1
cannot import 'store1': one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

Then I tried showing the pool by directory.

```
root@ubuntuserver:/# zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id
pool: store1
id: 15396841088549477814
state: ONLINE
action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier.
config:

    store1                                      ONLINE
      ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68AX9N0_WD-WMC1T0028936  ONLINE
      ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68AX9N0_WD-WMC1T1115383  ONLINE
      ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WMC4N1926000  ONLINE
      ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11DC449VTX  ONLINE
```

Then appended `-f store1`

```
root@ubuntuserver:/# zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id -f store1
cannot import 'store1': one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

Then I tried it by ID, just in case.

```
root@ubuntuserver:/# zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id -f 15396841088549477814
cannot import 'store1': one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I checked `smartctl` hoping to find evidence of a bad HDD. No CRC errors reported. So I hit `CTRL`+`ALT`+`F1` to look for any errors and saw some drive errors referencing `/dev/sdc`. I used `smartctl` to figure out what serial number the drive had **and replaced the SATA cable** and it imported just fine.

Strange but simple resolution at least.